# Warning about assignment from incompatible pointer type when using pointers and arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, warnings

For the `struct`

```
typedef struct sharedData
{
    sem_t *forks;
}sharedData;
```

I get a warning when I try to do this:

```
sharedData sd;
sem_t forks[5];
sd.forks = &forks; // Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

Am I misunderstanding or missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `&forks` has type

```
sem_t (*)[5]
```

That is, a pointer to an array of five `sem_t`s.  The compiler warning is because `sd.forks` has type `sem_t*`, and the two pointer types aren't convertible to one another.

To fix this, just change the assignment to

```
sd.forks = forks;
```

Because of C's pointer/array interchangeability, this code will work as intended.  It's because `forks` will be treated as `&forks[0]`, which does have type `sem_t *`.

Answer (score 1):

The above is a great explanation of but remember that

```
sd.forks = forks;
```

is the same as....

```
sd.forks = &forks[0];
```

I like the second one for clarity. If you wanted the pointer to point to the third element...

```
sd.forks = &forks[2];
```