# "Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type" when using a double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have a question about the warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type". Why does the following code

```
const char files[][128]={"file1","file2","file3"};
char **ptr;

ptr=files;
```

produce this warning? Something more complex is working just fine:

```
typedef struct
{
double **matrix;
}foo_struct;

void fun(foo_struct *foo)
{
double **ptr;
ptr=(*foo).matrix;
}
```

So I can't really see why the first one does give this warning, because I thought that something like files[][128] is of the same type as char **ptr. The only difference I see is that C knows about the span/size of the valid memory region, whereas in the second example it doesn't.

Here's something similar, which didn't help me though: [Warning about assignment from incompatible pointer type when using pointers and arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895121/warning-assignment-from-incompatible-pointer-type/17275721#17275721)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Has been asked many times. Possible duplicate of [Is 2d array a double pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586702/is-2d-array-a-double-pointer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files` has type `char (*)[128]`, not `char**`; there is no second level of pointer (and we're not talking about `const` yet; it's another can of worms).

This code should not show a warning (except the one for constness)

```
const char files[][128]={"file1","file2","file3"};
char (*ptr)[128];

ptr=files;
```

Answer (score 2):

That has to do with the fact that

```
const char files[][128]={"file1","file2","file3"};
```

makes `files` of type `const char [][128]` which is equivalent to a type `const char (*)[128]`.

In this scenario your data is laid out in blocks of 128 characters per string. Dereferencing `files` finds you a block of 128 characters.

On the contrast a `char **` expects to find an array of `char *` pointers to char when dereferencing. If you want `files` to be compatible with `char **` you have to declare it as

```
const char * files[]={"file1","file2","file3"};
```

Comment: declaring it like this gives exactly the same warning